# Two watches/iPhones disagree on weather

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, weather.app

My wife and I each have an iPhone with an Apple watch paired to it.  We’re sitting three meters from each other on the same cell carrier and the same WiFi.  Both watches say (correctly) that we’re in Springfield.

Yet one says current temperature is 97° with 98° predicted, and the other says 100° going on 101°.

**Why are they different (now and *always*)?**

Comment: Women always say they’re freezing, maybe you’ve stumbled onto sone physical evidence that proves an actual temperature difference. Alternatively, one of you icould be endothermic?

Comment: :-) But seriously, the number represents the temperature measured at some nearby location.  But … not the same location?    (Also, my wife always says it's hot in the house.)

Comment: When you say "same WiFi", I'm assuming that your in the same location (like a house/apartment).  I can see where there could be a temp variance within a city or town (one person in a city urban dwelling versus another in suburban/rural part), but not in the same localized area.  I can't replicate, even across the the two Android devices I have.  My Apple devices and the Amazon Fire Tabs all show the same weather forecast.  This might need a support call to Apple

Comment: Yes, "three meters apart" on the WiFi AP that I set up in our house.